# How to register a custom built for Kryptonite's ATPO Program?

Tags: lock, equipment

When registering for Kryptonite's ATPO Program [here](https://shop.kryptonitelock.com/atpo_order_forms/atpo-registration.html), you are asked for a bicycle make and model. With a custom-built, I have no idea what to provide there. I contacted customer service, with no reply after a week. Given the limited time frame where one can register for the ATPO Program after lock purchase, I am getting worried. From the corresponding terms and conditions, I see nothing that would exclude custom-builts, which would at least explain asking for a specific make and model.

Comment: Custom built meaning a frame with uprated components or fully custom meaning everything made from scratch?

Comment: Did you hand build the frame?  If so, put your name, or the name of whoever welded/brazed it.    Or is it a drop-down list and you can only select from makes and models listed ?

Comment: Re: custom-built: I did not laminate carbon sheets and the like. Instead, I just but the frame, fork, gears, and etc. and had my LBS turning everything into something rideable. So, and as I see it, @RoboKaren's answer has the info needed.

Comment: please clarify "but"   do you mean "I just bought the parts"   or "I just built the parts"  ?

Comment: Sorry Criggie, "but" was intended to be spelled as "bought"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Kryptonitewebsite,  looks like both the make and model are open-ended text entry forms. So I think you’d be ok to write something like:

> Make: Bike-builder’s-name
>
> Model: your-name

So if you had John Jones make your bike and you’re Carla Carlson then you could say:

> Make: JJones
>
> Model: Carlson
>
> Model Year: 2020

If you built the frame yourself, then I think you could name it anything you want.

For kryptonite, they need the bill of sale if you bought it or an appraisal if you built it yourself.

Kryptonite is a little famous in being ... slow ... in paying out on their “insurance” so you may be better off just listing your bike on your homeowner or renters insurance policy.

What’s important to remember is that from the perspective of kryptonite, insurance companies, the police, etc is that **the frame is the bike** for all intents and purposes. So you use the frame number for the serial number of the bike.